# Matplotlib: Histogram from a list of frequencies

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, histogram

I have a list x = [90, 100, 121, 123, 88]. These values in the list are frequencies of occurrence of an event in 5 different trials. I am looking to create a histogram from this list.

I simply tried:

```
plt.hist(x)
plt.show()
```

I get this:
[image: This is what I get but not what I am aiming to get]

I need something like this:
[image: Similar to what I need. Frequencies on the y axis. X-axis can simply be the indices]

Note: Very New to Python. And still learning when and how to use Stackoverflow.

Comment: You need a bar chart (`plt.bar`), not a histogram

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the list `x` contains the frequencies then use a bar plot:

```
x = [90, 100, 121, 123, 88]

plt.bar(range(1,6), x)
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.show()
```

[image]